# How I can use method to validate mobile numbers { 011xxxxxxxx and012xxxxxxxxand010xxxxxxxx}

Tags: android

```
String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";
            if (mobile_number.length() != 11 && 
 !mobile_number.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern) ) {

                mobile_number.setError("Please Enter correct mobile number");
                return;
            }
```

how I can use method to validate mobile numbers { 011xxxxxxxx and 012xxxxxxxx and 010xxxxxxxx}

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `PhoneNumberUtil` class:

```
package com.google.i18n.phonenumbers;

public static boolean isNumberValid(String countryCode, String phNumber) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(countryCode)) {// Country code could not be empty
        return false;
    }
    if (phNumber.length() < 6) {        // Phone number should be at least 6 digits
        return false;
    }
    boolean resultPattern = Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phNumber).matches();
    if (!resultPattern) {
        return false;
    }

    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    String isoCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(Integer.parseInt(countryCode));
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = null;
    try {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phNumber, isoCode);
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
}
```

Where countryCode is the dialcode of a country : 33 for France , 34 for Spain etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can check if number start with values you need or no, **ex :**

```
String mob = mobile_number.getText().toString();

if(mob.startsWith("010") || mob.startsWith("011") || mob.startWith("012")){

      //todo your logic here 

  }
```